# htaccess: 301 redirect on react site is causing repeating pattern

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

really weird behaviour.

On a subdomain of mysite https://staging.example.com I have the following htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
Redirect 301 /support /support/subsection
</IfModule>
```

this works perfectly fine on https://example.com but does not on staging.mysite.com

Here this happens: https://staging.example.com/support/subsection/subsection/subsection/subsection/subsection/subsection/subsection/subsection

I get this repeated pattern as if there was some loop or something going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect directive requires a complete URI as the redirect target. However, you can use RedirectMatch that allows you to specify a relative URI as the target.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/support$ /support/subsection
```

I think you get all those subsections for two reasons. The first reason is that you don't use a complete URI for the redirect. I think the documentation claims that you don't have to use it, a documentation typo I guess.

The second reason is because you don't tell the engine explicitly what you want, thus it will not always work as expected. When using .htaccess the rules are processed each time the .htaccess file is called. Since you didn't tell where to start and to end (^ $) it will (I think) be processed once per character and that seems to hold. However, if you use the httpd.conf file instead it would only be processed once.

Another benefit if you use httpd.conf is that you can enable logging to investigate complex mod_rewrite directives. To enable logging add the following to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 2
```